# How to pass parameters to Start method in Thread in java?

Tags: java

why can't we pass parameters to thread.start() method in JAVA? why java is not providing this facility?

Comment: Please share the code what you want exactly?

Comment: You can't. Btw why do you need that?

Comment: the 'start' method is just intended to 'start' something. it's like one-two-three : GO!! no parameters needed to do that

Comment: If it would accept a parameter, what would people do that do not need it? It is just unnecessary overhead not directly related to the interface itself. If you need additional information, pass it to your class through other channels, such as a constructor or a method.

Comment: I want to create a downloader thread and want to pass file_path as parameter to start() method. and java is not allowing me to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the parameter in the constructor to the Runnable object

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable {

   public MyClass(Object parameter) {

   }

   public void run() {
   }
}
```

or with lambda expression:

```
 private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    executor.submit(() -> {
        myFunction(parameter1);
    });
```

Comment: one possibility

Comment: Hmm. That does not do anything about the `Thread` though (daemon flag, name, stack size, etc). Of course, often people say `Thread` when they mean `Runnable`, so maybe this is the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `start()` method just starts execution of the `Thread`. It doesn't require any parameters because you can configure the `Thread` beforehand. For example, you can call `setDaemon(true)` before you start the thread.

If you are subclassing `Thread` you can create your own constructor or getters and setters to configure whatever domain-specific dependencies you want. (As an aside, I would suggest that you create a class that implements `Runnable`, rather than subclassing and coupling your object to `Thread`. You can then create a `new Thread(runnable)` when you need to run it in a thread).

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many of parameters combinations, which you may want to pass to the start method. All this combinations and their processing logic were incapsulated into Runnable interface. So, you could create custom implementation of Runnable and pass it to thread. This way is preferred.

If you really need it, you can inherit from Thread class and create constructor with parameters, setters/getters etc.

```
static class CustomThread extends Thread {
    int a;

    CustomThread(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

static class CustomRunnable implements Runnable {
    int a;

    CustomRunnable(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CustomThread(1).start();
    new Thread(new CustomRunnable(2)).start();
}
```